# Formula to Find if Number is between a Range in 2 Columns and then Pick 1st Column, or 2nd if Empty

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

There are 4 columns. 1st column has the result, 2nd column has a backup result if the 1st column is empty, the 3rd column has the low/floor value of range, and the 4th column has the high/ceiling value of range.

The Excel formula should check and see what row the search value sits in between columns 3 and 4, and then pulls column 1 if a value is found, or pulls column 2.

```
| 1st Column |  2nd Column|3rd Column ||3rd Column |
|------------|------------|-----------|------------|
| a          |az1         |    1      |        5   |
| b          |az2         |    6      |        10   |
| c          |az3         |    11     |        15   |
| -           |az4         |    16     |        20   |
```

Search Value 1: 13
Result: c

Search Value 2: 6
Result: b

Search Value 3: 19
Result: az4

Thank you in Advance for help and guidance!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O., please note that this is not a free code writing service. What have you tried and what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I have used this formula but it is capturing the row below instead of the current row. i.e., bringing back 'b' when the value is 4 instead of of 'a'. IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(COLUMN1,MAX((COLUMN3<=SEARCHVALUE)*(COLUMN4>=SEARCHVALUE)*(ROW(COLUMN1)))),INDEX(COLUMN2,MAX((COLUMN3<=SEARCHVALUE)*(COLUMN4>=SEARCHVALUE)*(ROW(COLUMN1))))),"No Scores")

Comment: Bosco answered your question. You should follow-up when people answer a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula for the all Excel versions.

In `G2`, enter formula :

```
=LOOKUP(F2,C2:C5,IF({0;0;0;1},B2:B5,A2:A5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way with Office 365 is:

```
=LET( x, G2,
      low, $A$1:$B$4,
      high, $C$1:$C$4,
        t, INDEX(low, MATCH(x,high,1),),
        INDEX( t, 1, IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(t,1,1)),2,1) ) )
```

You can put an IFERROR in it if you want it to give the "No Scores" result.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this using just the "normal" Excel formulas? I have 365...but the LET function doesn't seem to register in my formula bar. Do I need to enable something, or write this in Power Query?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user11092780 - Bosco's answer would be better (even in Office 365 actually).